# How to import only some of Material Components with Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, material-design

I'm using the Material Design Component Library in my Project and I'm importing it through CocoaPods.

```
pod 'MaterialComponents'
```

In the Frequently Asked Section of the Material Design Components Documentation is a Section about not importing all Components, only the ones needed. But I can't find how to do this.

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MaterialComponents.podspec](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/MaterialComponents.podspec), there are plenty of subspecs.

Example:

```
  mdc.subspec "BottomAppBar" do |component|
    component.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
    component.public_header_files = "components/#{component.base_name}/src/*.h"
    component.source_files = "components/#{component.base_name}/src/*.{h,m}", "components/#{component.base_name}/src/private/*.{h,m}"

    component.dependency "MDFInternationalization"
    component.dependency "MaterialComponents/Buttons"
    component.dependency "MaterialComponents/NavigationBar"
    component.dependency "MaterialComponents/private/Math"

    component.test_spec 'tests' do |tests|
      tests.test_spec 'unit' do |unit_tests|
        unit_tests.source_files = "components/#{component.base_name}/tests/unit/*.{h,m,swift}", "components/#{component.base_name}/tests/unit/supplemental/*.{h,m,swift}"
        unit_tests.resources = "components/#{component.base_name}/tests/unit/resources/*"
      end
    end
  end
```

If you want only the `BottomAppBar`, instead of:

```
pod 'MaterialComponents'
```

do

```
pod 'MaterialComponents/BottomAppBar'
```

Since there are a few `component.dependency`, you'll have them too (it's normal, `BottomAppBar` supposedly need them to work).